# How can I remove type 'false' inside a setState generic used in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

Hi I'm trying to use useState and handling a state with generics.
Inside a setState, I manipulated a fetched array with filter function and as you know it returns false.

so... I'll show my codes.

```
 const [mapItemsState, setMapItems] = useState<{ [k: string]: number | string }[]>([]);

 setMapItems(
     Object.entries(data)?.map(
        ([key, value]) =>
               Object.keys(mapItemListKor).includes(key) && {
               [key]: value as string | number,
        },
     )
     .filter(Boolean)        // I erased a false here!
 )
```

and this code returns this error
`Argument of type '(false | { [x: string]: string | number; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ [k: string]: string | number; }[]>'.`

I removed false using filter but it still detect `false`.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [mapItemsState, setMapItems] = useState<{ [k: string]: number | string }[]>([]);

 setMapItems(
     Object.entries(data).filter(Boolean)?.map(
        ([key, value]) =>
               Object.keys(mapItemListKor).includes(key) && {
               [key]: value as string | number,
        },
     )
 )
```

The issue you were having is that you were not filtering the array before it got mapped, meaning that the falses still get passed into the `.map`

Comment: There isn't a false value in `data`. `data` is a consist of  key value object.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I solved this problem as below.

```
setMapItems(
                Object.entries(data)
                    .filter(([key]) =>
                        Object.keys(mapItemListKor).includes(key),
                    )
                    .map(([key, value]) => {
                        return { [key]: value as string | number };
                    }),
            );
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as an Answer so that they can know it has been resolved.